# Displaying Images from Client-Machine in HTML

Tags: html, image, pathname

I was unable to display local images in both IE6 and IE7. Below is a page where you can see a demo:

http://www.thaiperfect.com/anytest/

Any advice?

Comment: You cannot do this for security reasons. Stop trying.

Answer (score 1):

Upload the image to your server and then show the image from that location. You can't access local machine files with javascript since it is a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** embed a picture in your website from an users computer. The path `c:\_topuponline\arrowup.jpg` will still look for an image in the server not in the usr's pc.

What you can do it ask the users t upload the picture to your server and then display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access contents on client's computer. I guess it would be very insecure. Why would you want to make this? Perhaps you should try giving the user the possibility of uploading an image. You should [check this tutorial](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the image from your server, rather than your local machine.  So if you upload your image to `http://www.thaiperfect.com/anytest/arrowup.jpg` then you can display it on the page using:

```
<img src="arrowup.jpg" height="150" width="174" border="0" alt="..." />
```

Answer (score -1):

some one told me that the answer may be in 2 links
http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r20721070-IE-IE-7-can-not-browse-local-files
http://www.phdcc.com/xpsp2.htm#securityoptions

but i didn't find an answer
furthermore I didn't my original question.
15:01 16/2/2010